# Is the second last "shipping" necessary?

Tags: redundancy, puns

[From this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23913/is-this-a-ship-shipping-ship-shipping-shipping-ships),

> This is a ship-shipping ship, shipping shipping ships.

[image]

The second to last word `shipping` seems to be redundant. Is it necessary? Does the sentence still preserve the same meaning if it is omitted? Would a general ship be any different than a shipping ship?

Comment: Well, a *ship* could be used for *travel*, *leisure*, *battle* (i.e. a *battleship*), *reconnoissance*, etc. But more important is that the reduplication enhances the *humor*. That's the point. (Absent the humor, the second clause, and in fact the entire meme, is technically "unnecessary").

Comment: Even if it were redundant, it's still having fun with the language, and that's a legitimate reason for having the word.

Comment: Parsing the sentence are you asking essentially "Aren't all ships made for shipping and therefore 'shipping ships'?"? or "Isn't 'shipping ship' redundant since it is already in the name 'ship' that it does shipping?"? Or "Are there non-shipping ships?"?

Comment: the last one best describes my question I think. Are there any non-shipping ships? Or, what would be the difference between saying "That is a ship" and "That is a shipping ship" ?

Comment: There are, indeed, non-shipping ships: destroyers, cruisers, guided-missile cruisers, submarines, and aircraft carriers. Also, trawlers, seafood processing ships, and ships of any type which have sunk are no longer shipping ships, as they do not move, though some of those may be known as a "former shipping ships". The difference between "that is a ship", and "that is a shipping ship" is that the former includes some naval vessels, and fishing ships, while the latter does not.

Comment: BTW, some of the vessels shown in the picture (specifically the bottom one on the far left, and the bottom two on the right) are not ships at all, but barges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence is

> This is a ship-shipping ship, shipping *shipping* ships.

The last *shipping* is an adjective, describing what kind of ships are being shipped. The second to the last *shipping* is the *verb* of that clause (the present participle of ship). It's not redundant*, as there are other kinds of ships.

It could be rewritten (and keeping the meaning)

> This is a ship-carrying ship, shipping cargo ships.

Comment: What exactly is a shipping ship? A cargo ship?

Comment: @user13267 - The one in the picture is a shipping ship for sure. There are cargo ships (they ship carge), there are passenger ships (they ship passengers), etc. Mostly, as Dan Bron stated, this is a humorous use of the words.

Comment: Why do you say your rewrite changes the meaning?  I think they are saying a "shipping" ship to *mean* cargo ship (as opposed to battleships, cruise ships, etc).  A battleship would be a "fighting" ship, a cruise ship might be a "partying" ship and a cargo ship would be a "shipping" ship.  Because when we talk about "shipping" stuff we're talking about cargo being moved.  Not that anyone ever says "shipping ship", but the meaning is clear as a parallel construction.  Or, so I think--do you disagree?

Comment: @msouth - I have to agree with you. I must have meant *without* changing the meaning. :-/ Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's necessary. The whole point of the sentence is to see how many times a form of the word "ship" could occur in a single sentence. In that sense, it's akin to

> Where James had had had John had had had had had had had had the teachers approval.

or properly punctuated

> Where James had had "had", John had had "had had"; "had had" had had the teacher's approval.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer the question about if or how the second to last 'shipping' is meaningful.

Comment: The meaning of the original sentence is of little consequence to the exercise. Lack of context of the OP limits my opinion on the matter, but if my suspicion is correct, the sentence is an exercise, perhaps for amusement. The second to last "shipping" is meaningful because it adds one more iteration of a form of the base quadrad (ship). Some indication that this is the case can be derived from the original site name, discernable above the last iteration of "ship"--"bigfun.be"